# Drarry Harry Potter fan fiction with Harry going to one of the Weasleys bachelor parties and getting a magical tattoo on his back

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

This fic involves Harry and Draco having a secret relationship and at some point Harry gets invited to one of the Weasleys bachelor parties and he ends up getting a magical tattoo on his back. Draco is there under the Invisibility Cloak the whole time but Harry doesn't find out until later. After the party Draco and Harry have rough sex against the brick wall in the alley outside.

At the very end of the fic Draco and Harry with all of Harry's friends are sitting on the quidditch pitch watching the twins firework display. Followed by Draco and Harry having sex under the bleachers.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be a fan fiction called ["Secrets"](https://archiveofourown.org/works/8184311/chapters/18751001) by [Vorabiza](https://archiveofourown.org/users/Biza/pseuds/Vorabiza)?

> Beginning with Draco's unexpected arrival at the Dursleys, Harry's summer after sixth year becomes filled with activity and many secrets. As his summer progresses, Harry generates several unexpected allies as he finds himself actively becoming the leader of the Light side.

Comment: I've added a brief description but you should [edit] to explain how this matches the OP's description and why this is correct. See [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193) for some general tips on that.